# Sum of columns in list of objects

Tags: java

My Problem is like below:. I have List Of Objects. I need to add column x2 with same column X3 and combine X1 columns. Later removed the old row. Please suggests.

```
                Input:-

             List<A> list = new ArrayList<>()
            A A1 = new A(X1=111, X2=10, X3= '333')
            A A2 = new A(X1=222, X2=20, X3= '333')
            A A3 = new A(X1=333, X2=2, X3= '444')
            A A4 = new A(X1=444, X2=5, X3= '444')
            A A5 = new A(X1=666, X2=6, X3= '777')

            list.add(A1).addd(A2).add(A3).add(A4).add(A4)

            OutPut should be like below:-
             { 
                Object A1 (list = {111,222}, x2= 30 , x3= '333')
                Object A3 (list = {333,444}, x2= 7 , x3= '444')
                Object A5 (list = {666}, x2= 6 , x3= '777')
            }


public class A {
   private long X1;
   private long X2;
   private String X3;
   private List<Long> list;
 }
```

Comment: In what context?  How is your program storing all this data currently?

Comment: you want to group by x3 column ? x1 is an array and x2 is an integer ?

Comment: currently my program storing in List<Objects> variable . After implement some logic, current list should change with new output.

Comment: @user84 `After implement some logic` we need to understand that logic, can you give more explanation about your variables ?

Comment: I have added the class with variables. I am looking for that logic only.

Comment: Okay, so you want to loop through the list and if X3 values are the same they should be combined so that X1 values are put into a list and X2 values are added together?

Comment: @Tim Hunter, thats true.

Comment: What value would `X1` have in the resulting combined object?

Comment: X1 should be null

Comment: So `X1` is `Long`, not `long` then?

Comment: once we are gettting "List<Long> list" under each A object. we don't require X1. we can make 0 also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (java 8+), with A as a mutable object (which i do not like):

```java
        List<A> objects = new ArrayList<>();

        A A1 = new A(111, 10, "333");
        A A2 = new A(222, 20, "333");
        A A22 = new A(222, 20, "333");
        A A3 = new A(333, 2, "444");
        A A4 = new A(444, 5, "444");
        A A5 = new A(666, 6, "777");

        objects.add(A1);
        objects.add(A2);
        objects.add(A22);
        objects.add(A3);
        objects.add(A4);
        objects.add(A5);


        List<A> output = objects
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                        Collectors.toMap(A::getX3, a -> {
                            a.getList().add(a.getX1());
                            return a;
                        }, (a, b) -> {
                            a.getList().addAll(b.getList());
                            a.setX2(a.getX2() + b.getX2());
                            return a;
                        }),
                        map -> new ArrayList(map.values())
                ));

        System.out.println(output);
```

and the output shows:

```
[A(X1=111, X2=50, X3=333, list=[111, 222, 222]),A(X1=333, X2=7, X3=444, list=[333, 444]),A(X1=666, X2=6, X3=777, list=[666])]
```

Comment: Thanks for solution. i think, a.getList() would be null initially . "a.getList().add(a.getX1())" will  give null pointer exception? any thoughts?

Comment: Ah sorry for my solution i had to initialize it with ˋList<Long> list = new ArrayList()ˋ

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're looking for something like this? This can definitely be simplified, but I think it has the output you have in mind. Be sure to break it down to understand how it works so you can do it yourself in the future.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<A> vals = new ArrayList<>();
    vals.add(new A(111, 10, "333"));
    vals.add(new A(222, 20, "333"));
    vals.add(new A(333, 2, "444"));
    vals.add(new A(444, 5, "444"));
    vals.add(new A(666, 6, "777"));

    List<Output> outputs = getOutput(vals);
    for(Output output : outputs) {
      System.out.println(output);
    }
  }

  public static class Output {
    public List<Long> X1 = new ArrayList<Long>();
    public long X2;
    public String X3;

    //Set initial values
    public Output(A value) {
      X1.add(value.X1);
      X2 = value.X2;
      X3 = value.X3;
    }

    //Add additional values
    public void addValue(A value) {
      X1.add(value.X1);
      X2 += value.X2;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return "X1: " + X1.toString() + ", X2: " + X2 +", X3: " + X3;
    }
  }

  public static class A {
    public long X1;
    public long X2;
    public String X3;

    public A(int x1, int x2, String x3) {
      X1 = x1;
      X2 = x2;
      X3 = x3;
    }
  }

  public static List<Output> getOutput(List<A> vals) {
    //Create return list
    List<Output> outputList = new ArrayList<>();

    //Copy given array
    List<A> values = new ArrayList<>(vals);

    while(!values.isEmpty()) {
      //Grab first value and remove it from list copy
      A value = values.get(0);
      values.remove(0);

      //Create output object
      Output output = new Output(value);

      //List for deleting objects processed
      List<A> deletionList = new ArrayList<>();

      //Process the rest of list to look for matching X3 values
      for(A otherValue : values) {
        if (value.X3.equals(otherValue.X3)) {
          deletionList.add(otherValue);
          output.addValue(otherValue);
        }
      }

      //Add output object to return list and remove processed values
      outputList.add(output);
      values.removeAll(deletionList);
    }

    return outputList;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for solution. i can not change output object. It should be "A" not "OutPut".